# bootstrap-table refresh custom handler

Tags: bootstrap-table

I am using bootstrap-table, and want add my custom handler for refresh buttons and not to run the default handler.
How I can do this?
Something like:

```
$('.refresh').click(function() {
    // refresh was clicked
});
```

Comment: a counter question would be 'why?'. Please explain what type of code you need to be executing, as `responseHandler` and various `on-load` and similar events might fit your bill even better. You can even your own ajax handler and pass it in as option to bootstrap-table - so frankly i cant see anything you cant do that doesnt require overwriting default ui handlers (that also wont actually affect the 'refresh' method itself, just that button)

Answer (score 0):

Click on the red ribbon on the right side to see the source [Refresh Documentation](http://issues.wenzhixin.net.cn/bootstrap-table/#methods/refresh.html)

```
$('.refresh').click(function() {
    $('#table').bootstrapTable('refresh');
});
```